# Updating UI from OnPostExecute(Async)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an array that represents a maze. On UI, the maze is represented as rows and columns of buttons. Inside doInBackground method of async task, I searched a path and initialize a solution array with the path that leads to goal. What I'm trying to do is update button text of those buttons to show a path leading to the goal. I'm doing this inside OnPostExecute. However, it doesn't work. It doesn't even execute the last line that enables the solution button. Where am I doing where?

```
private void updateUI() {
    Button cell;
    TableRow row;

    do {
        row = (TableRow) (State.maze.getChildAt(solution.row));
        cell = (Button) (row.getChildAt(solution.col));
        cell.setText(State.pathCell);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        solution = solution.next;
    } while (solution.next != null);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    updateUI();
    //Enable solution button
    State.solveResetButton.setEnabled(true);

}
```

UPDATE:
I checked to make sure solution variable contains a solution and it does contain valid data.I also tried removing sleep but to no avail.

UPDATE:
Logcat Output (The ones in red)

```
 02-23 13:09:15.471 4640-4640/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
 02-23 13:09:15.471 4640-4640/? E/Zygote: v2
 02-23 13:09:15.471 4640-4640/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
 02-23 13:09:15.471 4640-4640/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
```

Comment: are there any exceptions in your logcat?

Comment: an easy solution would be available if you can debug it..

Comment: can you post all of your code, are you running AsyncTask on serial Executor?

Comment: Is this an infinite loop?  It looks like you are never changing the solution.next while condition inside your do loop. Or does next always go to the next value until null?

Comment: @jacobhyphenated Damn I miss that one. But still it does not update the button.

Comment: @jacobhyphenated  Ok I found culprit. It was my stupid my mistake. I forgot to remove the comment from the line where I assigned State.pathCell. It was blank. If  you move your answer to reply, I'll mark it as right answer.

Comment: @user3273345 try removing the super.onPostExecute(result) from your onPostExecute call

Comment: @user3273345 added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `solution.next` is not updated in you while loop. This is causing an infinite loop, so your `updateUI()` method never stops executing.

Also, `onPostExecute` as part of an `AsyncTask` is always called on the main thread. You do not want to use `Thread.sleep` on the main thread. That is a great way to get ANRs.

With regards to how to accomplish this, there are a number of ways that might work.  Consider something like this with a Handler for the main thread:

```
private void updateUI() {
    Button cell;
    TableRow row;

    if (solution != null){
        row = (TableRow) (State.maze.getChildAt(solution.row));
        cell = (Button) (row.getChildAt(solution.col));
        cell.setText(State.pathCell);
        solution = solution.next;
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateUI(); 
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

You could also accomplish this with a new AsyncTask using `publishProgress` to call back to the UI  Thread

```
private void updateUI(){
    new AsyncTask<Solution, Solution, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Solution... solutions) {
            Solution solution = solutions[0];
            do {
                publishProgress(solution);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                solution = solution.next;
            }
            while(solution.next != null);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Solution... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Solution solution = values[0];
            row = (TableRow) (State.maze.getChildAt(solution.row));
            cell = (Button) (row.getChildAt(solution.col));
            cell.setText(State.pathCell);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //Enable solution button
            State.solveResetButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.execute(solution);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    updateUI();
}
```

Comment: So what is the right way to delay updating the button text so that only one button is updated at a time? Right now, it doesn't delay but updates all button at once.

Comment: @user3273345 I've edited my answer above to include some code samples. These are just 2 options you could take. There are plenty of ways to accomplish what you are looking to do.